# Construct a smooth immersion $h:M\to \mathbb R^n$ with $h(p)=h(q)$.

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I encountered such an exercise:

> Let $n,m$ be two positive integers with $n\geq 2m$ and $M$ be a smooth manifold of dimension $m$. Let $p,q$ be two distinct points on $M$. Show that there exists a smooth immersion $h:M\to \mathbb R^n$ such that $h(p)= h(q)$.

The [Whitney Immersion Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_immersion_theorem) tells us:

> If $M$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $m$, and $n\geq 2m$. Then for any $f\in C^\infty(M,\mathbb R^n)$ and any $\varepsilon>0$, we can find a $g\in C^\infty (M,\mathbb R^n)$ such that (1) $g$ is a smooth immersion from $M$ into $\mathbb R^n$; (2) $\|g(x)-f(x)\|_{\mathbb R^n}<\varepsilon$ for any $x\in M$.

Clearly, the Witney Immersion Theorem guarantees the existence of a smooth immersion $h:M\to \mathbb R^n$ (since $f:M\to\mathbb R^n$ defined by $f\equiv 0$ is smooth), but how can we construct a smooth immersion $h$ that satisfies the additional condition $h(p)=h(q)$? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider two open coordinate balls $U_p,V_p$ each containing $p$ such that $\overline {U_p}\subseteq V_p$. Similarly, consider $U_q,V_q$. Without loss of generality, let $V_p\cap V_q=\varnothing$. Construct smooth immersions $\lambda:U_p\to \Bbb R^n$ and $\mu\colon U_q\to \Bbb R^n$ such that $\lambda(p)=\mu(q)$, this is possible as $U_p,U_q$ are coordinate balls. Using bump functions supported on $V_p, V_q$ construct a smooth function $f\colon M\to \Bbb R^n$  such that $f\big|U_p=\lambda$ and $f\big|U_q=\mu$.

Comment: In particular, there is a closed set $K$ in $M$ such that $f\big|K$ is an immersion(this $K$ can be taken as a union of two small closed balls each contained in one of the $U_p$ or $U_q$). Finally, apply the theorem below, whose proof can be found [here](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Differential_Topology/aD8PCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Theorem+2.4.2+of+amiya+mukherjee+differential+topology&pg=PA60&printsec=frontcover):

Comment: **Theorem:** Let $\varphi\colon M\to \Bbb R^n$ be a smooth map, $\dim M = m$ and
$n ≥ 2m$. Let $\delta\colon  M\to (0,\infty)$ be a continuous function. Then $\varphi$ can be $\delta$-approximated by an immersion $\Phi \colon M \to \Bbb R^n$. Moreover, if $\varphi$ is an immersion
on a closed subset $K \subseteq M$, then $\Phi$ can be chosen so that $\Phi(x) = \varphi (x)$ for $x \in K$.

Comment: @SumantaDas Thx!